# Yahoo!Finance CSV file, error in price=5.05544704E8 (or similar numbers) and date=1/1/1970?

Tags: csv, quotes, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

someone experiment the same error while downloading CSV quotes from Yahoo!Finance web service ?
Trying to download by my APP but also by URL in a web browser I obtain this error:
in the l1 tag (last trade price) a number similar to 5.05544704E8, ...
int the d1 tag (last trade date) the following date 1/1/1970 
The problem appened in the last few days, (now is 21/07/2011) why?
thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yahoo financial results appear to be unreliable recently. This problem is not the only one, recently some stocks were given "N/A" (via CSV only, web pages were fine), some indexes were unavailable, etc. So this is not your error, it is just Yahoo web service giving wrong results because of their bugs or other problems.